# Как связать 2 таблицы?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица `Rajons`. В ней поля `id`, `rajon_id`

И есть таблица `Bars`. В ней поля `id`, `group_id`, `name`

Задача заключается в том, чтобы вывести список баров в нужном районе, но показывать нужно не `id`, а name бара.
`Rajons.rajon_id` и `Bars.id` между собой связаны. Еще раз напомню, что надо вывести имя бара

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.name as name FROM Bar b INNER JOIN Rajon r ON b.rajon_id=r.id WHERE r.id='someID';
```